# Dropdown not working in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, dropdownbox

In my application i have drop down select boxes in many places. In pop ups and in other forms also. This is working fine in all browsers but in IE.

I tried in older versions of IE also but still I am not able to select from drop down. 
Can anybody help me on this plsss

```
<label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></label> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9"> 
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCancelItem", 
        new List<SelectListItem> { 
            new SelectListItem{ Text=@Resources.Resources.O, Value = "1" }, 
            new SelectListItem{ Text=@Resources.Resources.C, Value = "0" } },
        new { @class = "form-control" }) 
</div>
```

Comment: you have to be a lot more clear than "not able to select from drop down", preferably with some code, and expected and actual results.

Comment: @AndrewCounts The default text is not changing even if select any other items in the drop down

Comment: this doesn't sound normal at all.  Can you list the code which contains the dropdowns for review?

Comment: <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3"></label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                            @Html.DropDownList("ddlCancelItem", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem{ Text=@Resources.Resources.O, Value = "1" },
                            new SelectListItem{ Text=@Resources.Resources.C, Value = "0" }
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>

Comment: edit your question please, it's not readable in the comments.

Comment: I added your code from your comment into the question for you, so others can read the code.  As a side note, I'm not seeing anything that explains why the selection won't change.  seems like very odd behavior that would be hard to reproduce.

Comment: @AndrewCounts :( the issue is there for all of my drop downs in the application in other browsers its working fine..